# I want to extract particular column from thousands of files and that particular column I want to print in new file new a column format

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

I want to extract particular column from thousands of files and that particular column I want to print in new file new a column format

input file1:

```
a e i    
b f j    
c g k    
d h l
```

input file2:

```
l p t   
m q u    
n r v    
o s w
```

input file3:

```
w 1 5    
x 2 6    
y 3 7    
z 4 8
```

I want to extract second column from each file for that I am using

```
awk ' { print $2 } ' > test.txt
```

now each extracted column want to print in new file column wise, here I have query.

Expected output file:

```
e p 1    
f q 2     
g r 3    
h s 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's all the files in the current directory: amend the glob pattern otherwise.

```
files=(*)
awk '{print $2}' "${files[@]}" | pr -t -s" " -${#files[@]} > output.file
# ............................................^^^^^^^^^^^^
# ................this is the number of files in the array
```

Demo

```
$ awk '{print $2}' file1 file2 file3 | pr -t -s" " -3
e p 1
f q 2
g r 3
h s 4
```

Comment: A very similar approach: `cut -"d " -f2 * | pr -3t"s " > test.txt`

Comment: Dear sir, Thank you for a response, but it is not working for my files. I am using windows base os.

Comment: That would have been important to say up front, don't you think? You'll need GNU tools for this answer. cygwin would do.

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@test /tmp]$ awk '{a[FNR]=a[FNR]?a[FNR]" "$2:$2}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){print a[i]}}' a b c



e p 1
f q 2
g r 3
h s 4
```